# Null check operator used on a null value, Flutter, State, LateInitializationError

Tags: flutter, dart, initialization, flutter-state, null-check

A simple app which returns a TextButton() with given name and given color.

Problem: I have to choose the color first and then name the card
but can't name the card and then choose the color.

I'd get an LateinitializationError with
late String cardTitle; and with
String? cardTitle; a: Null check operator used on a null value

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_colorpicker/flutter_colorpicker.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:cards/Models/card_data.dart';

Color pickerColor = Color(0xffFAFAFA);

class AddCard extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<AddCard> createState() => _AddCardState();
}

class _AddCardState extends State<AddCard> {
  void changeColor(Color color) {
    setState(() => pickerColor = color);
  }

  TextEditingController myController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    myController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    late Color newCardColor = Color(0xffFAFAFA);
    String? cardTitle;

    return Container(
      color: Color(0xff757575),
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
            topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
          ),
        ),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(140, 0, 140, 20),
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.grey.shade700,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                height: 4,
                width: 70,
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  flex: 3,
                  child: Material(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                    elevation: 10,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      autofocus: true,
                      controller: myController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                              borderSide: BorderSide.none),
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: pickerColor,
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(
                              color: useWhiteForeground(pickerColor)
                                  ? const Color(0xffffffff)
                                  : const Color(0xff000000),
                              fontSize: 18),
                          hintText: 'Nenne deine Neue Karte'),
                      style: (TextStyle(
                          color: useWhiteForeground(pickerColor)
                              ? const Color(0xffffffff)
                              : const Color(0xff000000),
                          fontSize: 20)),
                      onChanged: (newText) {
                        cardTitle = newText;
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 65,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                      child: TextButton(
                          style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                              shadowColor: pickerColor,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                              elevation: 10,
                              backgroundColor: pickerColor),
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.done,
                            color: useWhiteForeground(pickerColor)
                                ? const Color(0xffffffff)
                                : const Color(0xff000000),
                            size: 40,
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Provider.of<MyCardData>(context, listen: false)
                                .addCard(
                              cardTitle!,
                              newCardColor,
                            );
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          }),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 15, 10, 5),
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                height: 2,
                width: 70,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
              child: MaterialPicker(
                pickerColor: pickerColor,
                onColorChanged: changeColor,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

more on my git [git](https://github.com/panval/cards.git)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fix this:

- remove `late` initialization  when you set the value. `late` means that, you promise to the state that the value will be set later before used.
  `late Color newCardColor = Color(0xffFAFAFA);`
  to this
  `Color newCardColor = Color(0xffFAFAFA);`
- Move cardTitle outside the `build` method. because you want to update the state value later when `onChaged` in textField. If you initialize inisde the build method, the state value will not changed.
- call `setState((){})` to update your value `cardTitle`.

here full code:

```
Color pickerColor = Color(0xffFAFAFA);

class AddCard extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<AddCard> createState() => _AddCardState();
}

class _AddCardState extends State<AddCard> {
  void changeColor(Color color) {
    setState(() => pickerColor = color);
  }

  TextEditingController myController = TextEditingController();
  Color newCardColor = Color(0xffFAFAFA);
  String? cardTitle;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    myController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Color(0xff757575),
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
            topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
          ),
        ),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(140, 0, 140, 20),
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.grey.shade700,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                height: 4,
                width: 70,
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  flex: 3,
                  child: Material(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                    elevation: 10,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      autofocus: true,
                      controller: myController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                              borderSide: BorderSide.none),
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: pickerColor,
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(
                              color: useWhiteForeground(pickerColor)
                                  ? const Color(0xffffffff)
                                  : const Color(0xff000000),
                              fontSize: 18),
                          hintText: 'Nenne deine Neue Karte'),
                      style: (TextStyle(
                          color: useWhiteForeground(pickerColor)
                              ? const Color(0xffffffff)
                              : const Color(0xff000000),
                          fontSize: 20)),
                      onChanged: (newText) {
                        cardTitle = newText;
                        setState((){});
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 65,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                      child: TextButton(
                          style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                              shadowColor: pickerColor,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                              elevation: 10,
                              backgroundColor: pickerColor),
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.done,
                            color: useWhiteForeground(pickerColor)
                                ? const Color(0xffffffff)
                                : const Color(0xff000000),
                            size: 40,
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Provider.of<MyCardData>(context, listen: false)
                                .addCard(
                              cardTitle ?? '', 
                              newCardColor,
                            ); // when card title is null, it will set empty string
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          }),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 15, 10, 5),
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                height: 2,
                width: 70,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
              child: MaterialPicker(
                pickerColor: pickerColor,
                onColorChanged: changeColor,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```